# How to find all inputs which is not inside one div with css selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Html code:

```
<div id="div1">
  <div class="nest">
     <input name="i1"/>
  </div>
  <div>
      <input name="i2"/>
  </div>
  <input name="i3"/>
  <div>
      <input name="i4" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to find all inputs which are inside `#div1` but not inside `.nest` with css selector, which are `i2,i3,i4`. How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your markup, you *should* be able to use `:not()` with a child selector:

```
div:not(.nest) > input
```

If you need to restrict the scope to `#div1` you may need a slightly more complex selector:

```
#div1 > input, #div1 > div:not(.nest) > input
```

If you have arbitrary and uncontrolled levels of nesting, I'm not sure you'll be able to cover all cases using `:not()` alone.

And if you can't use `:not()` at all due to browser support issues, you're out of luck using pure CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to use the child selector:

```css
#div1 > input
```

Comment: This is working for the sample in this question, but not I'm looking for. So I make it a little complex :)

Comment: That's the child selector, not the descendant selector.

Comment: I guess that's why I had to write "to find immediate children" after that. Something didn't sound right. Thanks, @BoltClock, it's fixed. But unfortunately not what he's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
#div1 div:nth-child(2) > input, #div1 div:last > input
```

Comment: @Hassaan: Welcome to StackOverflow! Adding a short explanation and - as BoltClock has mentioned - using valid CSS, will improve the quality of your answer. Also consider http://jsfiddle.net/ for example creation.